# 'Node' object has no attribute 'insert' for Binary Tree Implementation

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, binary-search-tree, object-reference

I Understand this type of questions have been asked before and I am not blindly asking you guys this question as I have went through previous questions and I quite did not get it. This is the code below:

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data=data
        self.left=None
        self.right=None

class BST():
    def __init__(self):
        self.head=None

    def insert(self,data):
        if self.head is None:
            self.head=Node(data)

        if self.head:
            if data<self.head.data:
                if self.head.left is None:
                    self.head.left=Node(data)
                else:
                    self.head.left.insert(data)

            if data>self.head.data:
                if self.head.right is None:
                    self.head.right=Node(data)
                else:
                    self.head.right.insert(data)  #Actual error point

l1=BST()
l1.insert(2)
l1.insert(4)
l1.insert(6) #Getting the error while inserting this
```

I understand I either need to put the `insert` method inside `Node` class or inherit the `Node` class properties in to `BST` class but I am having hard time to implement both solutions, could you guys please walk me through both solutions, an explanation with written code would be really helpful to me .

You might be tired of seeing these questions, you are all experts here and you know how hard it could be for a beginner and especially I don't want to start off with unclear concepts.

Comment: stackoverflow isn't a tutorial website, so what you're asking it off-topic in my opinion.

Comment: @martineau could you at least gimme a solution to my error?

Comment: I'm not going to give you a complete solution, but you may find it helpful to understand that `left` and `right` should be **subtrees**, not standalone **nodes**. So you don't need `class Node` at all - just put `data` inside `class BST`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve the problem is to give `Node`s a method to attach another to it based on how its value compares to its own and have the tree `class` call it. The tree class instance can then just call its head `Node` to do this. The code below shows how to do that.

Notably, I've also changed the tree class so one will never be empty by making the `head` a `Node` with a unique data value when it's created. Doing this means the only time a check for an empty tree needs to be done is when a `TypeError` is raised when trying to attach data to the tree — instead of over-and-over again, recursively, in the `Node.attach()` method. Implement it this way makes the code simpler and run faster. The check is done by seeing if the tree's head is not a special value which couldn't possibly be real data.

Such special values are referred to as "[sentinel values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value)" and it's important to make sure they're distinguishable from any possible legal value. In Python you can create an instance of the built-in (largely featureless) [`object`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#object) class to do get one.

```
class BinaryTree:
    SENTINEL = object()  # Unique value.

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = Node(self.SENTINEL)

    def insert(self, data):
        try:
            self.head.attach(data)
        except TypeError:
            if self.head.data is self.SENTINEL:  # Empty tree?
                self.head.data = data  # First is special case.
            else:
                raise

    def print(self):
        self.head.print()
        print()


class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def attach(self, data):
        if data < self.data:
            if self.left is None:
                self.left = Node(data)
            else:
                self.left.attach(data)
        elif data > self.data:
            if self.right is None:
                self.right = Node(data)
            else:
                self.right.attach(data)

    def print(self):
        if self.left:
            self.left.print()
        print(self.data, end=' ')
        if self.right:
            self.right.print()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    tree = BinaryTree()
    tree.insert(2)
    tree.insert(4)
    tree.insert(6)
    tree.print()  # -> 2 4 6
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the details, just wondering why did you have to write `insert` methods in both classes ?

Comment: I did it that way because your testing code was calling the `insert` method of the tree class instance, which seemed like a descriptive name. You can easily rename the one in the `Node` class something else if you find having two of them confusing. The one in the `Node` class is more-or-less private in the sense that users of the tree class don't use it directly so it's not really part of its own "public" interface.

Comment: Okay now it makes more sense , thanks for your time and explanation , I appreciate it .I am upvoting your answer , by the way is there any article you would recommend for "Sentinel" values?

Comment: Thanks for doing that. The use of "sentinel" values has been around for a long time. I first learned of them in a book about data structures written by Niklaus Wirth. There's some information about them and their use in programming in the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value) on the topic.

Comment: P.S. I changed the name of `Node` class' `insert()` method to `attach()` because that's a better description of what it does (affixes a new `Node` to the current one).